# 'Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens' in Android Application in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am getting an error saying 'Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens' in and Android project named LunchList in Eclipse in 2 Java files:

the Type of error it's showing is a 'Java Problem' ,in 'Line 1', the Resource being  ._LunchList.java and 
 ._Restaurant.java
and the Path as '/LunchList/src/apt/tutorial

I imported the project and there were some errors which I removed. But this error couldn't be eliminated as the Java files it was in cannot be edited (it shows 'Access is denied').

The src folder and its subfolder also contain an error because of this but the Java files in the subfolder namely LunchlList.java and Restaurant.java do not how any error in them. I am new to this development environment. Could anyone please tell me how to get rid of these errors so I could run the application?

The src folder java files:

LunchList.java

```
package apt.tutorial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LunchList extends Activity {
    Restaurant r=new Restaurant();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(onSave);
}

private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
public void onClick(View v)
    EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    EditText address=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.addr);
    r.setName(name.getText().toString());
    r.setAddress(address.getText().toString());} };
}
```

Restaurant.java

```
package apt.tutorial;
public class Restaurant {
private String name="";
private String address="";

public String getName() 
{    return(name);    }

public void setName(String name)
{    this.name=name;    }

public String getAddress()
{    return(address);    }

public void setAddress(String address)
{    this.address=address;    }
}
```

Comment: There are syntax errors in the code but since we don't have crystal balls, we can't tell you exactly what they are. Please edit the question and add the relevant code. However, a wild guess: Since the error is on line 1, there are some unicode BOM characters at the beginning of file, put there by your text editor.

Comment: My bad!
Here's the code..

I cannot figure out how to delete the characters from the file because it keeps showing that access is denied to that file. Is there a way around this problem!?

Answer (score 2):

Delete ._LunchList.java (*all files starting with ._xyz.java*) file in the src folder or your package folder. These files are **hidden** so you have to mark option to show hidden files in your file explorer.

Comment: When I migrated from Mac to Linux I had this problem, I had to delete all hidden files in the **src** folder and **sub folder** (any file that starts with ._xxx.java)

Comment: yes same thing happened when I migrated my project from mac to ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix project properties by right clicking on the project > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties
After that clean your project.
If it doesn't work then try to delete the project and then re-import it.
Check its libraries they could be broken or corrupted.

Comment: Thanks...
I performed the first 2 but they didn't seem to help..
How do I check whether any library is corrupt/broken or not!?

Comment: open your libs folder and check the size of libraries if it is 0 bytes it will be corrupted                                          Right click on your project then click on Android and the check the box if there is any problem